# taiga-back when conecting rabbitmq (in Docker) raise RuntimeError: Invalid url

Tags: rabbitmq, taiga

I'm trying to run **Taiga 6.7.0 with docker compose** from https://github.com/kaleidos-ventures/taiga-docker and when trying to create a project (at web interface) the following error occurs in the **taiga-back** container:

```bash
File "/taiga-back/taiga/events/events.py", line 35, in backend_emit_event backend.emit_event(message=json.dumps(data), routing_key=routing_key, channel=channel)
File "/taiga-back/taiga/events/backends/rabbitmq.py", line 45, in emit_event connection = _make_rabbitmq_connection(self.url)
File "/taiga-back/taiga/events/backends/rabbitmq.py", line 28, in _make_rabbitmq_connection raise RuntimeError("Invalid url") from e RuntimeError: Invalid url
```

What can be wrong?

I was set this enviroment variable:

```
RABBITMQ_URL="amqp://${RABBITMQ_USER}:${RABBITMQ_PASS}@taiga-events-rabbitmq:5672/taiga"
```

But the error still occours